# How to extract thread Id in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I got the useful knowledge on  usage of `Message Id` and `Unique Id` by using this http://blogs.mulesoft.org/total-traceability/ . Need clarification on which one is the thread. In Mule debugger View, we could see MessageRoot ID and Unique Id only. But how could I take a `Thread ID`.

Is it Message id(Message root Id) and Thread Id are same?. I believe it is not. Please confirm.
If not, how can we take the thread id. Because I have multiple flows and calls in my flow.

Looking for understanding the scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessageId` is a UUID generated for every `MuleMessage` object instance generated in Mule. By default, the `RootId` is the same as the `MessageId`. However, there are some Endpoints (such as the JMS) that share the `RootId`, sending it as a property. Imagine you have a `flow1` that sends a message (with id `'xxx-xxx-xxx'`) to a JMS queue "Foo" and a `flow2` that receives a message from the same JMS queue, the message in the `flow2` will have an id `'xxx-xxx-yyy'` and the RootId `'xxx-xxx-xxx'`. This way you have a relation between the messages generate in the flows.

The `threadId` is a long value that identifies a java thread. You can obtain the id the current thread using the code `Thread.currentThread().getId()`. In MEL it would be `#[java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getId()]`

Comment: @Krumia Thanks for your help. It works!! I have accepted the answer since it given the current solution!!

Comment: @star: Your thanks should go to Nuno, actually. He is the answerer and I just [edited the post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27099575/revisions) to improve formatting.

Comment: oh!! okay. I'm not sure who has given the exact answer since both of the names appeared. Also I could see someone down voted it though the provided answer works for me. @Nuno Thanks for your great help!!